# non-privileged normal user passing environment variables to /bin/login

Tags: freebsd, telnet, user-management

Suppose that in FreeBSD (or linux maybe) there is a non-privileged normal user (non-superuser). And there is a telnet standalone (I know that telnet is usually run under inetd) running under (owned by) this user. (Suppose that there was no original, root-owned telnet running.) This telnet server is programmed so that it does not check ld_* environment variables before passing it to /bin/login owned by root that has setuid set up.

The question would be: 
1. Will this telnet work?
2. If it does work, will it even be able to pass environment variables to /bin/login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose that in FreeBSD (or linux maybe) there is a non-privileged superuser.

"Non-privileged superuser" is a contradiction in terms; the word "superuser" itself means a user having all privileges.

> This telnet server is programmed so that it does not check ld_* environment variables

I'm not sure if this is relevant. The telnet server doesn't have any special privileges, so stripping `LD_*` variables is not very useful...

> 1. Will this telnet work? 2. If it does work, will it even be able to pass environment variables to /bin/login?

It will partially work, but it will likely be unable to bind to the standard Telnet port due to missing CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE privilege.

Yes, it will be able to pass environment variables to `login`, just like any other process can. However, at least on Linux, the loader (ld-linux.so) discards all `LD_*` variables before running a setuid program, so a setuid-`login` would be unaffected by them.